# Do you know about this weird thing. "AS3, Button width cannot change by setStyle(). However, inline CSS can change width."

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

### I'm making GraphPaper like WEBapp and notice.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application name="test2"
  xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <mx:Button width="500" height="500" />
</s:Application>
```

---

can make big square Button.

But

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application name="test2"
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
            mx|Button {
                width: 500;
            }
    </fx:Style>
    <mx:Button />
</s:Application>
```

---

This doesn't work

And

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application name="test2"
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
            mx|Button {
                fontSize: 500;
                width: 500;
            }
    </fx:Style>
    <mx:Button label="test" />
</s:Application>
```

---

can extend button width 'just similar to text width'.

Thus I predict that Button's width can be defined by fontSize or icon.
Button itself width cannot be change externally.
But inline CSS only can change Button's width irregularly.

I think this is Adobe's bug.  How do you thin about this and do you know something about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be corrected, but I believe inline CSS operates on the `StyleManager` to pass operations to the `SkinClass` using the `ISimpleStyleClient` interface. IE using the `.getStyle()` and `.setStyle()` functions. Height and Width are not part of the `StyleManager` they are properties of the `DisplayObject`.

MXML allows you to mix calls to class properties and skin/style properties inline, but CSS doesn't

Comment: Thank you Sir.  I'll check the difference between skin properties and style property.  Then, I try to think about how skin work, where should I write.

Now I've wrote this app using almost AS3 code(for the sake of coding loop and control structure), I'll try other way too. 

Thanks, CyanAngel.